# Metaclass default argument value (Delphi 2009)

Tags: delphi, metaclass, default-arguments

I want to give a default value in a metaclass argument:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  end;

type
  TMyClassMetaClass = class of TMyClass;

procedure MyProcedure(const AMetaClass: TMyClassMetaClass = TMyClass);
```

It is possible? In Delphi2009 it gives me the error: E2026 Constant expression expected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the rules of the language, a metaclass is not a constant expression. So your best bet is to use overloading instead:

```
procedure MyProcedure(const AMetaClass: TMyClassMetaClass); overload;
procedure MyProcedure; overload;
```

And in the implementation:

```
procedure MyProcedure(const AMetaClass: TMyClassMetaClass);
begin
  ....
end;  

procedure MyProcedure;
begin
  MyProcedure(TMyClass);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, it fulfil the requierement.

Comment: You also could make the default value `nil` and treat `nil` as your desired class.